# Redirect 301 htaccess old domain to new domain without copying equivalent urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to have a full domain `301 htaccess redirect` without copying the urls, so I want to make if the old domain url is: `rucab.net/auth`, is redirect to `www.residenciarucab.es` (root domain), not redirecting to `www.residenciarucab.es/auth` (same equivalent url). The root old domain redirect good to the root new domain, but with the pages happens like I said before.

I tried with that but didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ https://www.residenciarucab.es/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this rule on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rucab\.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.residenciarucab.es/ [R=301,L]
```